# svg coordinate of g element larger than other element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I want to place a small circle on the x axis of g element when clicking on  top of g element

```js
var allStates = $("#lk1");

allStates.on("click", function() {
  
 var width = parseFloat(event.target.getBoundingClientRect().width);
                  var height = parseFloat(event.target.getBoundingClientRect().width);
                  alert("Area of the rectangle is: " +width +"x"+ height);
  alert(event.target.getBoundingClientRect().x+'x'+event.target.getBoundingClientRect().y)
  //alert(event.target.getBoundingClientRect().left+'x'+event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top)
  x=lk1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  y=event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'cir');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '5');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx',x);
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
  element.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'red');
 //element.innerHTML= ped_pb;
lk1.appendChild(element);
            
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<g id="lk1" transform="translate(40,80)" fill="#0FF"><g transform="scale(1.5)" stroke-width=".0005" style="border: 1px dashed black;"><path i:knockout="Off" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.411,0.506V13.17h12.697V0.506H10.411z"></path><g> <defs><path id="XMLID_1_" d="M0,0.253h23.87v23.809H0V0.253z"></path>      </defs>      <clipPath id="XMLID_2_"><use xlink:href="#XMLID_1_"></use></clipPath><path i:knockout="Off" clip-path="url(#XMLID_2_)" fill="none" stroke-width="1.0131" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="M10.411,0.506h12.697V13.17H10.411V0.506z"></path></g><g stroke-width=".000000000000000000005"><path i:knockout="Off" clip-path="url(#XMLID_4_)" stroke-width="0.0317" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1.523,23.777l7.555-8.422l-1.523-1.361l-7.523,8.422L1.523,23.777zM7.904,21.782l1.777-8.611l-8.38,2.723c-0.54,0.158-0.825,0.729-0.667,1.267c0.19,0.538,0.762,0.823,1.301,0.665l6.698-2.185l-1.301-1.172l-1.429,6.902c-0.095,0.538,0.254,1.076,0.794,1.203C7.269,22.668,7.777,22.321,7.904,21.782z"></path></g></g></g></svg>
```

Unfortunately g element returns larger coordinate values.

Answer (score 0):

remeber that `transform="scale(1.5)"` is changing `getBoundingClientRect()` results. Just simple divide result of `element.target.getBoundingClientRect().width` by your scale value.

Unfortunately It is mentioned only in polish version of MDN [Polish MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

> Beginning with Gecko 12.0 (Firefox 12.0 / Thunderbird 12.0 / SeaMonkey 2.9), the effect of CSS transformation is included in the bounding rectangle algorithm.

Comment: thank u so much. it is showing the x position from view port not from svg. i computed x cord of g - x cord of svg element to get the actual x cord based on svg for plotting other elements